# What are the alternatives to using django signals?

Tags: django, signals

I am working on a project where I need to recalculate values based on if fields changed or not. Here is an example:

```
Model1:
    field_a = DatetimeField()

    calculated_field_1 = ForeignKey(Model2)

Model2:
    field_j = DatetimeField()
```

If field_a changes on model1 I have to recalculate the value for field calculated_field_1 to see if it needs to change as well. The calculations that are done require me querying the database to check values of other models and then determining if the value of the calculated field needs to change.

Example) field_a changes then I would have to do this calculation

```
result = Model2.objects.filter(field_j__gte=Model1.field_a)
If result.exists():
    Model1.field_a = result.first()
Model1.save(update_fields=(‘field_a’,))
```

This is the most basic example I could think of and the queries can be much more complicated than this.

The project started out with one calculation when a field changed so I decided the best approach was to use django signals. Months later the requirements have changed for the project and now there are several other calculations that I had to implement that are very similar to the example above. I have noticed that my post_save function is getting out of hand and I am just wondering what alternatives there are to using signals. Although the post_save calculations I do now take far less than half a second, for the sake of my question pretend they took a second or more.

A valid answer cannot include doing these calculations on the fly when I pull them from the db. We use a validation framework that requires me to set these values on the model and querying on the fly has been an approach we attempted but for performance reasons it was not viable. Also, on field change one of the requirements is that the user needs to see the results of the calculated field so this has to happen synchronously.

What are some alternative approaches to using this pattern?

Comment: What is the issue with the post_save taking a second or more? Are these stalling the request/response cycle? If this is your problem, you could use the post_save signal to trigger a celery worker to perform this work. This would then be asynchronous with respect to the HTTP request.